# Setting aliases in Yii2 within the app config file

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm trying to set an `alias` in `Yii2` but I'm getting a `Invalid Parameter / Invalid path alias` for the below code that is placed in the app config file:

```
'aliases' => [
    // Set the editor language dir
    '@editor_lang_dir' => '@webroot/scripts/sceditor/languages/',       
],
```

If I remove the `@` it works.

I noticed you can do this:

```
Yii::setAlias('@foobar', '@foo/bar');
```

...but I would prefer to set it within the app config file. Is this not possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `config` folder create file `aliases.php`. And put this:

```
Yii::setAlias('webroot', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/web');
Yii::setAlias('editor_lang_dir', '@webroot/scripts/sceditor/languages/');
```

In `web` folder in `index.php` file put:
`require(__DIR__ . '/../config/aliases.php');`

Before:

`(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();`

If run `echo` in view file:

`echo Yii::getAlias('@editor_lang_dir');`

Show like this:

`C:\OpenServer\domains\yii2_basic/web/scripts/sceditor/languages/`

Comment: Thanks. adding the `require(__DIR__ . '/../config/aliases.php');` to index.php helped me..

Answer (score 13):

Yii2 basic application

To set inside config file, write this inside $config array

```
'aliases' => [
        '@name1' => 'path/to/path1',
        '@name2' => 'path/to/path2',
    ],
```

Ref: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html

But as mentioned [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html),

The @yii alias is defined when you include the Yii.php file in your entry script. The rest of the aliases are defined in the application constructor when applying the application configuration.

If you need to use predefined alias, write one component and link it in config bootstrap array

```
namespace app\components;


use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;


class Aliases extends Component
{
    public function init() 
    {
       Yii::setAlias('@editor_lang_dir', Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/scripts/sceditor/languages/');
    }
}
```

and inside config file, add 'app\components\Aliases' to bootstrap array

```
    'bootstrap' => [
        'log',        
        'app\components\Aliases',        
],
```

Answer (score 2):

`@webroot` alias is not available at this point, it is defined during application bootstrap :

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.3/framework/web/Application.php#L60

No need to define this alias yourself, you should simply use another one :

```
'aliases' => [
    // Set the editor language dir
    '@editor_lang_dir' => '@app/web/scripts/sceditor/languages/',
],
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve on @vitalik_74's answer

you can place it in config/web.php instead(if you are using the basic yii app, I'm not sure about the main config file in the advance version, but the same applies, just put the require on the main config file) so that it gets shorten to:

```
require(__DIR__ . '/aliases.php');
```

Comment: I prefer this answer, especially when taking the new environment / init script of yii into account.