# Yii2 how to change default aliaes @vendor ==@app/vendor to @webroot/vendor

Tags: php, yii2

now the default aliaes

```
 @vender Defaults to @app/vendor.
```

how to change it defaults to @webroot/vendor.

---

## ignore below info

when using assetsBundle in the namespace repo.

```
namespace repo\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class RepoAsset extends AssetBundle {

  public $sourcePath = '@repo/media';

  public $css = [
    'css/site.css',
  ];

  public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
  ];
}
```

I can't publish the depends asset.

```
The file or directory to be published does not exist: /Users/tyan/Code/php/myii/repo/vendor/bower/jquery/dist
```

but the real location of the jquery is

```
/Users/tyan/Code/php/myii/vendor/bower/jquery/dist
```

it this happends to bootstrapAsset too.I try to echo the

```
@app //seems it's location is /Users/tyan/Code/php/myii/repo
@vendor //it's /Users/tyan/Code/php/myii/repo/vendor
```

seems that @app and @vendor add my own namespace in it automatically which not make sence.

BTW. I define the @repo aliases in the web.php config file.

```
  'aliases' => [
    '@repo' => dirname(__DIR__),
  ],
  'controllerNamespace' => 'repo\\controllers',
```

because I want to change the default namespace.

Comment: see [Extension Aliases](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html#extension-aliases) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797051/setting-aliases-in-yii2-within-the-app-config-file

Comment: I fix the problem by relocate the yii2-bootstrap assetbundle because I build the project from scache.